# Outputting SVN hook messages

Tags: svn

I have a subversion repository on my Linux machine that is set up to export a new build of a project every time a new commit occurs using a post-commit hook.  I would really like to be able to provide an output message to the committer containing some status information once the hook completes.  Is it possible to redirect the output of the hook to come after the standard commit messages?

For example:

> owner@dev-machine:/working/dir$ svn commit
>       Sending FILE1
>       Sending FILE2
>       Transmissing file data ...
>       Committed revision 13.
>       **Exporting project...**
>       **Successfully exported to mysite.com**

The addition of the last two lines is the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html), the only way to output anything to the client from post-commit is to write to standard error and then exit with a non-zero status. However, this will result in output like the following:

```
Committed revision 200.

Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
Exporting project...
Successfully exported to mysite.com
```

Comment: Well, that's a bummer, but thanks for the workaround!